# onPause() and onResume() order when replacing Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have 2 Fragments that I transition using this code:

```
 private void switchTo(Fragment frag) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.contentPanel, frag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

When I transition between the 2 Fragments, I would need to do some cleaning up in between. I put this cleanup code in the onPause() method of the fragment. The problem now is that onResume() of the 2nd Fragment takes place before onPause() of the 1st Fragment

I put a print statement in each fragment's onPause(), onResume(), and onStop() of both Fragments and this is the order it spits it out.

```
FRAGMENT 2 RESUMED
FRAGMENT 1 PAUSED
FRAGMENT 1 STOPPED
```

Is there a way to coordinate these 2 fragments such that I can clean up in between each transition?

Comment: Perform [`transaction.setAllowOptimization(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setAllowOptimization(boolean)) before commiting it.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Please put this as the answer so I can designate it.

Answer (score 1):

Perform [`transaction.setAllowOptimization(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setAllowOptimization(boolean)) before commiting it.

Google introduced optimizations, which are by default turned on in latest versions of support libs.

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setAllowOptimization(boolean)):

> The side effect of optimization is that fragments may have state changes out of the expected order. For example, one transaction adds fragment A, a second adds fragment B, then a third removes fragment A. Without optimization, fragment B could expect that while it is being created, fragment A will also exist because fragment A will be removed after fragment B was added. With optimization, fragment B cannot expect fragment A to exist when it has been created because fragment A's add/remove will be optimized out.

Those optimizations sometimes break logics that we as users of that API are dependent of.